# The Wither Cage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to show my friends that I can do cool stuff in Minecraft, so I decided to show them a wither that is alive and moving but can't escape a cage. What should I use for the cage and what dimensions should I use? I tried bedrock but it escaped. I think my walls were too short. Any suggestions?

Comment: Too... short? As in, you left the top open? You do realize the wither can *fly*.

Comment: of course i know the wither can, when i said too short i meant the ceiling was not high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Barriers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier).

Build a cage (with a ceiling, withers *do* fly!) however you'd like, and line the inside of the cube with barrier blocks. This'll keep him locked inside and all outside players safe but still able to see the wither.